# Python replace with re-using unknown strings

Tags: python, replace, capture-group

I have an XML in which I'd like to rename one of the tag groups like this:

```
<string>ABC</string>
<string>unknown string</string>
```

should be

```
<xyz>ABC</xyz>
<xyz>unknown string</xyz>
```

ABC is always the same, so that's no issue. However, "unknown string" is always different, but since I need this information extracted, I also want to keep the same string in the replacement.

Here's what I got so far:

```
    import re
    #open the xml file for reading:
    file = open('path/file','r+')
    #convert to string:
    data = file.read()
    file.write(re.sub("<string>ABC</string>(\s+)<string>(.*)</string>","<xyz>ABC</xyz>[\1]<xyz>[\2]</xyz>",data))
    print (data)
    file.close()
```

I tried to use capture groups, but didn't do it correctly. The string is replaced with weird symbols in my XML. Plus, it's printed twice. I have both the unchanged and the changed version in my XML, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're experiencing is not due to your regex pattern. The backslash (`\`) in the strings are escaping proceeding characters thus resulting in the *weird symbols* that you see.

```
>>> print "hello\1world"
helloworld
>>> print r"hello\1world"
hello\1world
```

Always use the [raw string notation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) to define your re patterns.

```
>>> data = """
... <string>ABC</string>
... <string>unknown string</string>
... """
>>> print re.sub(r"<string>ABC</string>(\s+)<string>(.*)</string>",r"<xyz>ABC</xyz>\1<xyz>\2</xyz>",data)

<xyz>ABC</xyz>
<xyz>unknown string</xyz>
```

Comment: Thanks! I do get the xyz and ABC replacement now, but the unknown string is still in weird characters in my XML. The back reference is still not working.

Comment: Can you show an example? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Have you checked that the weird chars are not already in the XML document you're working on?

Comment: There are no weird characters in the input XML, the input looks exactly like I mentioned in the example above:
     <string>ABC</string>
     <string>blablabla</string>
When I execute the command you suggested to use I get the follwing output in the python shell:   
<xyz>ABC</xyz> <xyz>˥</xyz> 
My line break is gone and there's an upside down "L" between the second tag group.
In my XML it looks like this:
<xyz>ABC</xyz>SOH<xyz>STX</xyz>
SOH and STX are written in white letters on black background. I opened the file in Notepad++.

Comment: SOH and STX are what you get when escaping 1 and 2, i.e. `"\1"` and `"\2"`. Are you sure you've used the raw string notations for both arguments to `re.sub`?

Comment: I did use the r" ", however I don't really know what to do with 1 and 2. How do I access the capture groups?

Comment: As in the example posted in my answer, use `\1` in the substitution pattern to include contents of the first captured group and `\2` for the second. It appears to work as expected when I tried it. Also shown working here: http://ideone.com/fuEIc

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was just a bit confused because you said before not to escape 1 and 2. Thanks for your patience, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you including the content in your replacement operation? All you need to do is:

- Replace `<string>` by `<xyz>`.
- Replace `</string>` by `</xyz>`.

It would take two operations but the intent of your code would be clear and you don't need to know what `unknown string` is.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this: All my tag groups have <string> </string> around them, and I need to extract just a single group that has the name ABC. Therefore I'd like to rename this specific group. I don't know another less complicated solution to this issue.